# How to remote hook/operation hook after /Users/Reset call?

Tags: loopbackjs

I have this, but its not hitting it when I do a *POST Users/Reset

```
User.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) {
    console.log('Saved %s#%s', ctx.Model.modelName, ctx.instance.id);
  } else {
    console.log('Updated %s matching %j',
      ctx.Model.pluralModelName,
      ctx.where);
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: What do you do in `Reset` remote method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no predefined method for `/users/reset` in loopback. So there must be some remote methods defined for using this. I am not sure what you really want to ask but i think this will solve your problem.

```
module.exports = function(User){

    User.reset = function(msg, cb) {
      console.log("Reset Post method is getting called");
      cb(null, 'Greetings... ' - msg);
    }

    User.remoteMethod('reset', {
          accepts: {arg: 'msg', type: 'string'},
          returns: {arg: 'greeting', type: 'string'}
    });
};
```